# Displaying a comment box on customized ActiveAdmin Show page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using [ActiveAdmin](http://www.activeadmin.info). By default, the comment box will appear at the bottom of the show page, but after I customize it that comment box block disappears.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Book do
  scope :all, :default => true
  scope :publish

  show do
    attributes_table :name, :description, :owner, :company, :publish, :publisher
  end 
end
```

How can I add the comment box back to the show page?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I got Answer :-P

```
ActiveAdmin.register Book do
  scope :all, :default => true
  scope :publish

  show do
    attributes_table :name, :description, :owner, :company, :publish, :publisher
    active_admin_comments # Add this line for comment block
  end 
end
```

Just add "active_admin_comments" at the end of show block. 
I found it on source code of [demo site](https://github.com/gregbell/demo.activeadmin.info)